# Reading from that stream and sending text to another form's textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, updating

I have a readstream opened in a form. I'm reading from that stream and sending text to another form's textbox . i want the text to be updated to the textbox as soon the text arrives in readstream.
code in first form:->

```
 f2.ShowDialog(); //f2 is second form's object
 while (true)
 {
    string inp_msg = sr.ReadLine();

    f2.set_text(inp_msg);
    this.Refresh();              
 }
```

set_text function defined in second form:->

```
 public void set_text(string msg)
 {
    //MessageBox.Show(msg);            
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + msg +  "\r\n";
    //Application.DoEvents();
 }
```

the problem is that the textbox is not updating .

Comment: Your `while` loop would run forever, add some `break` on some condition in your loop.

Comment: it is for continously reading the readstream

Comment: If so, you need to let the `UI thread` free, you should create another thread to read the stream.

Comment: while loop is itself in a thread which is reading the stream

Comment: but you show your `form2` in that thread. I mean `form2` should be shown in `UI` thread, and your while loop should be in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'f2.ShowDialog()', try calling:

```
f2.Show();
```

When you call the method 'ShowDialog()', the code after that statement isn't executed until the form is closed.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx for more details.

Comment: i've tried this but the program hangs and shows "not responding" dialog box

Comment: As King King commented, you're running in an infinite loop. You need a break; statement to stop the while loop from looping over and over again.